# angularjs $resource - display 2 get requests as one object

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering what's the best way to display two GET requests as one object, the requests have a couple of properties that match on both of them, but i can't figure out how to merge them and display them as one on the view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please share some code, show us what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should make a single GET/POST call to the server, and then on the server side you should fetch the data from first and second resource (probably db table ). Then merge the data in array from both resources and finally send the response back as JSON.

Hope I understood that this is what you are asking for hope that helps :)